# Get value between two CGPoint before animating (uiscrollview)

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiscrollview

Sorry for my poor english.

In my work, We made a app which show a high resolution image into a UIScrollVIew. Besides, the user can play a MP3 that animate the position and zoom of UIScrollView from one second with a specific duration showing the detail of image that MP3 is talking about. Currently, the audio play from second 0 to the end sequently. User can´t interactuate with UIScrollView when the MP3 is playing

Now we want that the user can change the current time when is playing, I´m not sure how calculate the position when the user select a second placed in the midst of one animation.

Example:

Second 1: Duration 4; Second 8: Duration 2; Second 20 Duration 10; Second 31 Duration 3;

If the user select the second 24, we would want animate during 6 seconds, but keeping in mind the original position that UIScrollView should have since second 20 to 24 from original animation.

We are using uiview animation (animateWithDuration) with zoomToRect (animated:NO) method from UIScrollView

I´m not sure how calculate those intermediate values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, whether I really get you right or wrong. But you can set the animations progress to a progress value that is in relation to the start point and the total duration of the animation. I. e. in your case

```
float animationStartPoint = 20.0; // Start of the animation
float duration = 10.0;            // Its duration
float partialStartPoint = 24.0;   // user selected start point

NSAnimation *animation = …;
…
animation.currentProgress = (partialStartPoint-animationStartPoint)/duration;
[animation startAnimation];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think NSAnimation is exclusive for MacOS and don't exist in iOS framework.

Comment: Oh, sorry, did not pay attention to that.